# What is DOM GC event?

Tags: dom, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I am just trying to understand the chrome Dev tools. I came across the term "DOM GC" in the performance tab. Can someone please explain what it means?

Answer (score 0):

"GC" in this case stands for Garbage Collection. Kind of hard to find what "DOM GC" is when looking it up as-is. Here's a good [link](https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc) that talks about different GC events that happen in the browser.